# Center .css Button, Display javascript Content Locker and Display java Alert onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im having a few problems (I've highlighted them in the code):

Problem 1: I don't know how to get the #dl_buttn centred - (45% is nearest) - is there any way to 'Align:centre'?
Problem 2: Im trying to display a content locker onClick - However my locker isn't popping up? - is the code wrong to display a javascript content locker?
Problem/Question 3: Instead of displaying a message on the second click, i would like to display a java alert - I have tried to do this, but failed - could anyone help me out? - (the id for it is 'message')

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Passupload Passowords - Get the Passwords for your .RAR Files Here!</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#dl_buttn {
    position:absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 280px;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<center>
<body bgcolor="#3c3c3c" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
 <input type="image" id="dl_buttn" src="images/GETRARPASS.png"  alt="Submit Form" position:absolute;  onClick="imageClick()" />

 <span id="message" style="display:none">You have completed this part!</span>
<script type="text/javascript"> // --------------PROBLEM 3 
/* <![CDATA[ */

var count = 0;
function showMessage () {
   if (count++ > 0) {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display="block";
   }
}

function changeImage() {
   document.getElementById("dl_buttn").src = "images/REVEALPASS.png"
}

function imageClick() {
   var fileref = document.createElement('script');
   fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); 
   fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://tvserieslink.com/CLP/locker.js?guid=44f3fa3f991e9a34');
   showMessage(); 
   setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);
}

/* ]]> */    
</script>
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Puloaaa.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1100" height="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/Pulo_01.gif" width="1100" height="150" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/Pulo_02.gif" width="1100" height="650" alt="">
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->

</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Sorry I'm a noob & Sorry for posting the whole code - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

a) You have improper syntax for your input, remove the `position:absolute` css as it doesn't belong there:

```
<input type="image" id="dl_buttn" src="images/GETRARPASS.png"  alt="Submit Form"  onClick="imageClick()" />
```

b) use `margin: 0 auto;` to center your dl_buttn and get rid of the absolute positioning.

**Problem 2:**
You are creating a script element in the DOM but you are not attaching it anywhere. You need to use `document.body.insertBefore` or `insertAfter` or similar to attach it to the document.

**Problem 3:**
To display a javascript alert use `alert('Your message here.');`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - i've got the javascript alert working now! I don't quite understand where to place the 'margin: 0 auto' code nor the 'document.body.insertBefore' code, could you perhaps point out to me where its meant to go? - Thanks for the help, really appreciate it,

Comment: take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qt7S/) for direction. not sure what your locker.js is doing but you can just modify the insert statement to place it wherever you want on the page.

Comment: You are a massive help! Got most of it working now - i seriously appreciate your help, there is only one problem with it now, and that is that the content locker.js only appears after the button has been pressed for a second time (i want it to appear on the first click of the button) - Sorry I'm such a noob lol, thanks again!

Comment: it's because the locker is not there on the first click, you are attaching it AFTER the first click, then it is able to fire on the second click. you need to attach the locker when the user hits the page by wrapping that portion in a document ready statement. take a look at this updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/8Qt7S/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qt7S/1/).

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for your time, help and effort! Ive been struggling with this for days (new to coding) - Cheers!